# Проблема с функцией, ошибка "string is not function"

Tags: javascript

Проблема в том, что если строка

```
           mass_child[j].style.display = option_display
```

находится выше

```
       (function(i){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                                mass_child[i].style.opacity = option_opacity
                        },100)
                    }(j))
```

то тогда появляется ошибка string is not function. Почему?

```
      for(var j = 0; j < mass_child.length; ++j){
            name = mass_child[j].className
        if(name == undefined) {
            continue
            }else{
                if(name == mass_class_name[0] || name == mass_class_name[1] || name == mass_class_name[2]){                                
                      (function(i){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                    mass_child[i].style.opacity = option_opacity
                            },100)
                        }(j))       
                         mass_child[j].style.display = option_display
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Блин, сколько раз говорить: всегда ставьте точку с запятой после выражения!

У вас получается:

```
mass_child[j].style.display = option_display  (function(i){....
```